# Query containing Logic

Tags: sql-server

```
 empno     emailID
--------------------
1           A@gm.com
2           B@gm.com
3           C@gm.com
2           BB@gm.com
1           AA@gm.com
1           AAA@gm.com
3           CC@gm.com
```

**Write a query so that result will be :--**

```
 empno     emailID
--------------------
1           A@gm.com,AA@gm.com,AAA@gm.com
2           B@gm.com,BB@gm.com
3           C@gm.com,CC@gm.com
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in MySQL and looks like this:

```
SELECT empno, GROUP_CONCAT(emailID)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY empno
```

Unfortunately `GROUP_CONCAT` does not exist in SQL Server but you can use `FOR XML PATH` or one of the other workarounds posted as answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005).

Comment: @Rosh: I have now included SQL that will work in MySQL. Note that it will not work in SQL Server.